# Authorize Microsoft Graph User with OAuth 2.0 type to Appsmith

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, postman, appsmith

**Intro**

I want to use [Appsmith](https://www.appsmith.com/) for internal applications.

In my Appsmith applications, I need to login Office365 Users.

In my understanding, to do that I have to "Get access on behalf of user", as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user).

[In this tutorial](https://youtu.be/3RTHY3jScmA?t=389), the friend is describing how to do Postman requests for MS Graph API calls, where I was able to successfully do that.

Appsmith also provides a "Create new API" option, where you can also have a OAuth 2.0 Authentication datasource, where I can run my HTTP requests and get the responses.

**The Question**

[In this tutorial](https://youtu.be/3RTHY3jScmA?t=389) from the minute I share it, the user needs to press the button in order to get a new access token. I was wondering If this is able to be done in Appsmith **ONLY** from the application's User Interface, or in Postman without having to press the button "get new access token".

**EDIT**

In more detail, I would like to implement in Appsmith the following flow only via the UI.

1. Make GET Request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={{client_id}}6&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://app.appsmith.com/api/v1/datasources/authorize&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read&state=12345`
2. Login with my account through the dialog box
3. Redirect to `https://app.appsmith.com/api/v1/datasources/authorize?code=[code]`
4. Make POST Request to the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant_id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

with body:

```
{
    code: [code] (how do I get it),
    client_secret: {{client_secret}},
    client_id: {{client_id}},
    scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read,
    redirect_uri: https://app.appsmith.com/api/v1/datasources/authorize
}
```

**So, the Main Question is: How do I get the [code] from step 3, so I can use it in the body of step 4**

**Edit 2**

Appsmith also provides `curl` option. Could I solve this via curl?

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible to access from the application interface yet since the OAUth is configured for a single datasource and not separately for every user today. You can authorise the OAuth app with a common set of credentials so your users need not authenticate it themselves

Comment: Hey Nikhil! First of all congratulations on the great work on Appsmith! Secondly, I am not sure what you mean by your answer. The thing is that I need the [code] query param from step 3, in order to use it at the body in step 4 and get a token for the logged-in user, so I can later call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me and get the user's information. We can have a chat in Appsmith if you want to :) Have a great day!

Comment: @IraklisBekiaris in this case, you should configure your redirect URL back to the application page instead of the datasource/authorise endpoint. That endpoint is meant to be used only if you are directly configuring oAuth for the datasource and not manually creating it yourself. Then on the redirect, you can access {{appsmith.URL.queryParams.code}} which will have the authorization code that you need

Comment: Hey Nikhil! Yes, I thought of this solution too! Thank you for your valuable feedback. I was planning to post an answer here in case someone else has the same requirement.